How to configure the fingerprint reader of a HP ENVY x360 Convertible 13 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
This is the error message I get:

Impossible to enroll:
GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available

Laptop:

HP ENVY x360 Convertible 13-ay0xxx


It would be helpful to add the PCI-ID of your fingerprint reader to your question with an edit. Acquire it via lspci or lsusb.
